# Pointing to source file from IDLE editor in python

Tags: python, file-io, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-idle

I'm working from the book called "Building Machine Learning Systems with Python".  I've downloaded some data from MLComp to use as a training set.  The file I downloaded (20news-18828) is currently in /Users/jones/testingdocuments/379

The book instructs code as follows:

```
import sklearn.datasets
MLCOMP_DIR = r"D:\data"
data = sklearn.datasets.load_mlcomp("20news-18828", mlcomp_root=MLCOMP_DIR)
print(data.filenames)
```

I've tried changing MLCOMP_DIR = /Users/jones/testingdocuments/379 and various combinations thereof, but cannot seem to get to the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
MLCOMP_DIR = r"D:\data"
```

implies that you are on Windows, while

```
MLCOMP_DIR = /Users/jones/testingdocuments/379
```

will not work, but with quotes added, implies that you are not on Windows, unless you left of `'C:'`.  If you run the program from a console (or start Idle from a console with `python -m idlelib`, you should see some error message.